# Jump to a specific div using JS

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with several submit button including one to edit user.
When clicking on it you display the "edit div" using php.

What I want is the site to scroll down to the div.
I'm using this function [JS Fiddle Jump](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/x3edvp4t/), it is actually working great as long as I don't use it with my submit button...

Here is my button:

```
echo"
<form action='' method='POST'>
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning btn-circle' title='Editer' name='edit' value='$row[id]' onclick='jump(\'test\')'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
</button>
</form>
";
```

First I tried to do an onclick action to trigger the jump() function but never worked, I believe it's because of my indentation.

I also tried to trigger the jump() function in the php code displaying the div.

```
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'jump("test");',
    '</script>'
    ;
```

Obviously I have a `<div id="test"></div>` at the bottom of the page just to try.

Nothing worked yet with this submit button. If you have any idea about what could be causing this issue, hit me up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Button type `submit` submits form immediately using HTTP method as `method` attribute and URL as `action` attribute. To prevent it, add to your function parameter `e` representing event and method

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that all the html of the different sections is already there and you want to jump to a section when you click a button.

If that is the case, there is no reason to submit a form to the server, you just need to move to the correct section on the page.

So you don't need a form for the button and it's type should not be `submit` but just `button`:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-circle' title='Editer' name='edit' value='$row[id]' onclick='jump(\'test\')'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
```

An alternative would be to return `false` from your `onclick` handler, but that does not seem necessary here.

Comment: Actually I tried it but I need this `type="submit"` because I'm recovering the id of the user through this button.

Comment: @SimonCo You have not posted enough code for me to get a clear picture, but what id? If you are talking about `$row['id']`, perhaps you can pass that to your `jump()` function as a parameter.

Comment: Here is the entire page: https://paste.ofcode.org/sWL2bxzm7H8fg8hAvT9Va5

Comment: But my problem seems to be the page keeps refreshing